# Adding Selection Functionality to the Table Row

Tags: android, selection, tablelayout, tablerow

Here is my code to add rows to TableLayout dynamically. Every row is having two Textviews.

```
final TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tbl);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);               

TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);

createView(tr, tv1,  "hello1");
createView(tr, tv2, "hello2");

tl.addView(tr);              


public void createView(TableRow tr, TextView t, String viewdata)  {

t.setText(viewdata);
t.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
t.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
tr.addView(t); // add TextView to row.
}
```

How can i set the selection functionality to that rows ? I have to start a new Activity after clicking on the row. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    tr.setClickable(true);
    tr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivityToBeLaunched.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```